# Div with slanted edges on two sides

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a 100% width row with a div that has slanted edges and images on both sides.

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFX1r.png)

Everything I've seen online only involves one side slants.

I've tried pseudo elements/skewing, but can't seem to get them to work while keeping the images on the left and right side of the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share any of the markup you've tried already / need to keep?  It'd help in coming up with something you could use without much modification

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ look under "Parallelogram". If that's not it, share your code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slanted_div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  background: #f2d600;
  text-align:center;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:5.2;
 margin:0 auto;
}

span {
  transform: skew(20deg); 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slanted_div">
<span>Div with Text</span>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking?

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you do the following on the inner span: ```transform: skew(20deg); display: block;``` you can get the text to go back to being unskewed.